# Need help with a mystery null pointer exception

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, null-pointer

I'm getting Null Pointer Exception from some recent code changes and I can't figure out where it's coming from.

I've put ** around the new code. Any help would be appreciated!

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, OrderItem_Trigger: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object

Class.OrderItem_TriggerHandler.updateStartDate: line 80, column 1
Trigger.OrderItem_Trigger: line 14, column 1: []

Trigger code:

```
trigger OrderItem_Trigger on OrderItem (after insert, after update) {
List<Id> newOrderItemIds = new List<Id>();
List<OrderItem> updateItemStartDate = new List<OrderItem>();
Set<Product2> orderedProducts = new Set<Product2>();
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isInsert){
    for(OrderItem o : trigger.new){
        newOrderItemIds.add(o.Id);
        if(o.ServiceStartDate__c == null){
            updateItemStartDate.add(o);
            orderedProducts.add(o.Product2);
        }
    }
    **if(!updateItemStartDate.isEmpty() && !orderedProducts.isEmpty()){
        OrderItem_TriggerHandler.updateStartDate(updateItemStartDate, orderedProducts);
    }**
    if(!newOrderItemIds.isEmpty()){
        OrderItem_TriggerHandler.updateOpportunity(neworderItemIds);
    }
    if(!updateItemStartDate.isEmpty()){

    }
}

List<Id> updateUnitPriceList = new List<Id>();
if(trigger.isAfter && trigger.isUpdate){
    for(OrderItem o : trigger.new){
        OrderItem oldO = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id);
        if(o.SBQQ__QuotedListPrice__c != oldO.SBQQ__QuotedListPrice__c){
            updateUnitPriceList.add(o.Id);
        }
    }
    if(!updateUnitPriceList.isEmpty()){
        OrderItem_TriggerHandler.updateUnitPrice(updateUnitPriceList);
    }
}
}
```

Class:

```
public with sharing class OrderItem_TriggerHandler {
@future
public static void updateOpportunity(List<Id> orderItemIds){
    List<OrderItem> orderItems = [SELECT Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c 
                                    FROM OrderItem 
                                    WHERE Id IN: orderItemIds];
    Map<Id,Id> quoteLineOrderItemMap = new Map<Id,Id>();
    List<Id> quoteLineIds = new List<Id>();

    if(!orderItems.isEmpty()){
        
        for(OrderItem o : orderItems){
            quoteLineOrderItemMap.put(o.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c, o.Id);
            quoteLineIds.add(o.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c);
        }
    }

    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLineItems = [SELECT Id,SBQQ__QuoteLine__c,OpportunityId 
                                                FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                                                WHERE SBQQ__QuoteLine__c IN :quoteLineIds];
    
    Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();

    if(!oppLineItems.isEmpty()){ 
        List<OpportunityLineItem> oppLinesToUpdate = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();   
        for(OpportunityLineItem opp : oppLineItems){
            opp.Order_Line_Item__c = quoteLineOrderItemMap.get(opp.SBQQ__QuoteLine__c);
            oppLinesToUpdate.add(opp);
            oppIds.add(opp.OpportunityId);
        }
        if(!oppLinesToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            Database.update(oppLinesToUpdate, False);
        }
    }

    List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLines = [SELECT Id,Ordered__c 
                                            FROM SBQQ__QuoteLine__c
                                            WHERE Ordered__c = False AND Id IN :quoteLineIds];
    
    if(!quoteLines.isEmpty()){
        List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c> quoteLinesToUpdate = new List<SBQQ__QuoteLine__c>();
        for(SBQQ__QuoteLine__c q : quoteLines){
            q.Ordered__c = True;
            quoteLinesToUpdate.add(q);
        }
        if(!quoteLinesToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            Database.update(quoteLinesToUpdate, False);
        }
    }

    /*if(!oppIds.isEmpty()){
        List<Opportunity> wonOpps = [SELECT Id,StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN :oppIds AND StageName != 'Closed Won'];
        for(Opportunity o : wonOpps){
            o.StageName = 'Closed Won';
        }
    }*/

}

public static void updateUnitPrice(List<Id> updateUnitPriceList){
    List<OrderItem> orderItemsToUpdate = [SELECT Id,UnitPrice,Additional_Disc__c,SBQQ__QuotedListPrice__c 
                                            FROM OrderItem 
                                            WHERE Id IN :updateUnitPriceList];
    for(OrderItem o : orderItemsToUpdate){
        if(o.Additional_Disc__c > 0){
            o.UnitPriceForceOverride__c = (1-o.Additional_Disc__c) * o.SBQQ__QuotedListPrice__c;
        } else {
            o.UnitPriceForceOverride__c = o.SBQQ__QuotedListPrice__c;
        }
        o.UnitPrice = o.UnitPriceForceOverride__c;
    }
    Database.update(orderItemsToUpdate, False);
}

**public static void updateStartDate(List<OrderItem> itemsMissingStartDate,Set<Product2> orderedItems){
    map<Id,Decimal> itemsWithLeadTime = new map<Id,Decimal>();
    List<OrderItem> orderItemsToUpdateDate = new List<OrderItem>();
    if (!orderedItems.isEmpty() && !itemsMissingStartDate.isEmpty()) {
        for(Product2 p : orderedItems){
            Decimal leadTime;
            if(p.Lead_Time__c == null){
                leadTime = 0;
            } else {
                leadTime = p.Lead_Time__c;
            }
            itemsWithLeadTime.put(p.Id, leadTime);
        }
        for (orderItem o : itemsMissingStartDate) {
            Integer leadTimeDays = itemsWithLeadTime.get(o.Product2Id).intValue();
            
            o.ServiceStartDate__c = Date.today().addDays(leadTimeDays);
            orderItemsToUpdateDate.add(o);
        }
    }
    if(!orderItemsToUpdateDate.isEmpty()){
        Database.update(orderItemsToUpdateDate,False);
    }
}**
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class OrderTriggerHandler_Test {  
private static ID StandardAccountRecordID = [SELECT ID FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 
'Account' AND Name = 'Standard Account' LIMIT 1].Id;

@isTest
private static void testOrderUpdate() {
    ERP_Company__c testERPCompany = new ERP_Company__c(Name='US-AX-01');
    testERPCompany = (ERP_Company__c)TestFactory.createSObject(testERPCompany);
    insert testERPCompany;

    Approval_Routing__c testEntity = new Approval_Routing__c(
        Name = '660',
        Management_Entity_Id__c = '660',
        Management_Entity_Name__c = 'Test Management Entity'
    );
    insert testEntity;

    List<Account> accountsToInsert = new List<Account>();
    Account testAccount = new Account(recordTypeId = StandardAccountRecordID);
    testAccount = (Account)TestFactory.createSObject(testAccount);
    testAccount.Name = 'Test';
    accountsToInsert.add(testAccount);
    insert accountsToInsert;

    
    Id testPricebookId = Test.getStandardPricebookId();
    

    Product_Hierarchy__c testHierarchy = new Product_Hierarchy__c(
        Product_Code__c = '480',
        Product_Description__c = 'PS STOPPLE Fittings',
        Family_Code__c = '1200',
        Family_Description__c = 'ISOLATION FITTINGS PROSERIES LOR',
        Sub_SBU_Code__c = '110',
        Sub_SBU_Description__c = 'HT&P Consumables - HP',
        SBU_Code__c = '00',
        SBU_Description__c = 'HT&P PRODUCTS'
    );
    insert testHierarchy;
    
    List<Product2> productsToInsert = new List<Product2>();
    Product2 testProd = new Product2(
        Global_List_Price__c = 100,
        Name = 'Test Product',
        Product_Code__c = '480',
        Part_Number__c = '0001',
        Product_Hierarchy__c = testHierarchy.Id,
        **Lead_Time__c = 5**
    );
    testProd = (Product2)TestFactory.createSObject(testProd);
    productsToInsert.add(testProd);
    insert productsToInsert;
    /*Id testProdId = testProd.Id;
    List<PricebookEntry> standardEntryList = [SELECT Id FROM PricebookEntry 
                                                WHERE Product2Id = :testProdId 
                                                AND Pricebook2Id = :testPricebook.Id 
                                                AND CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD' LIMIT 1];
    PricebookEntry standardEntry = standardEntryList[0];*/
    List<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntriesToInsert = new List<PricebookEntry>();
    PricebookEntry standardEntry = new PricebookEntry(
        Pricebook2ID = testPricebookId,
        Product2ID = testProd.ID,
        UnitPrice = 100,
        IsActive = True
    );
    standardEntry = (PricebookEntry)TestFactory.createSObject(standardEntry);
    pricebookEntriesToInsert.add(standardEntry);
    insert pricebookEntriesToInsert;
    PricebookEntry pbe = [Select Id from PricebookEntry LIMIT 1];
    
    
    List<Opportunity> oppsToInsert = new List<Opportunity>();
    Opportunity testOpp = new Opportunity(
        AccountId = testAccount.Id,
        ERP_Company__c = testERPCompany.Id,
        Management_Entity__c = testEntity.Id,
        Customer_Needed_Date__c = Date.today(),
        Pricebook2Id = testPricebookId
    );
    testOpp = (Opportunity)TestFactory.createSObject(testOpp);
    oppsToInsert.add(testOpp);
    insert oppsToInsert;

    List<OpportunityLineItem> oppItemsToInsert = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
    OpportunityLineItem testItem = new OpportunityLineItem(
        OpportunityId = testOpp.ID,
        PricebookEntryID = pbe.ID,
        UnitPrice = 100,
        Quantity = 1
    );
    testItem = (OpportunityLineItem)TestFactory.createSObject(testItem);
    oppItemsToInsert.add(testItem);
    insert oppItemsToInsert;

    List<ERP_Account__c> erpAccountsToInsert = new List<ERP_Account__c>();
    ERP_Account__c testERPAccount = new ERP_Account__c(
        Account__c = testAccount.Id,
        ERP_Company__c = testERPCompany.Id,
        Management_Entity__c = testEntity.Id,
        Payment_Terms__c = 'Net 30',
        Total_Credit__c = 100,
        Available_Credit__c = 0
    );
    testERPAccount = (ERP_Account__c)TestFactory.createSObject(testERPAccount);
    erpAccountsToInsert.add(testERPAccount);
    insert erpAccountsToInsert;

    /*List<SBQQ__Quote__c> quotesToInsert = new List<SBQQ__Quote__c>();
    SBQQ__Quote__c testQuote = new SBQQ__Quote__c(
        SBQQ__Account__c = testAccount.Id,
        ERP_Company__c = testERPCompany.Id,
        Management_Entity__c = testEntity.Id,
        SBQQ__Opportunity2__c = testOpp.Id,
        SBQQ__Primary__c = TRUE,
        Country_of_Destination__c = 'United States',
        SBQQ__PriceBook__c = testPricebook.Id,
        ERP_Account__c = testERPAccount.Id
    );
    testQuote = (SBQQ__Quote__c)TestFactory.createSObject(testQuote);
    quotesToInsert.add(testQuote);
    insert quotesToInsert;

    SBQQ__QuoteLine__c testQuoteLine = new SBQQ__QuoteLine__c(
        SBQQ__Quote__c = testQuote.Id,
        SBQQ__Product__c = testProd.Id,
        SBQQ__PricebookEntryId__c = standardEntry.Id,
        SBQQ__Quantity__c = 1
    );
    insert testQuoteLine;*/
    
    Order testOrder = new Order(
        AccountId = testAccount.Id,
        ERP_Account__c = testERPAccount.Id,
        //SBQQ__Quote__c = testQuote.Id,
        Opportunity = testOpp,
        PoNumber='Test',
        Description__c ='Test',
        Status='Draft',
        EffectiveDate = date.today(), 
        Management_Entity__c = testEntity.Id, 
        Bill_To_Name__c = 'Test', 
        Market_Sector__c = 'Mixed', 
        Ship_To_Name__c = 'Test',
        BillingStreet = '123 Test',
        BillingCity = 'New York',
        BillingState = 'New York',
        BillingPostalCode ='10003',
        BillingCountry = 'United States',
        ShippingStreet = '123 Test',
        ShippingCity = 'New York',
        ShippingState = 'New York',
        ShippingPostalCode ='10003',
        ShippingCountry = 'United States',
        Description = 'Test',
        Type = 'Order',
        Start_Date__c = date.today(),
        Pricebook2Id = testPricebookId
    );
    insert testOrder;

    List<OrderItem> orderItemsToInsert = new List<OrderItem>();
    OrderItem testOrderLine = new OrderItem(
        //SBQQ__QuoteLine__c = testQuoteLine.Id,
        OrderId = testOrder.Id,
        Product2 = testProd,
        PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id,
        Quantity = 1,
        UnitPrice = 100,
        ServiceStartDate__c = date.today()
    );
    orderItemsToInsert.add(testOrderLine);
    **OrderItem testOrderLine2 = new OrderItem(
        //SBQQ__QuoteLine__c = testQuoteLine.Id,
        OrderId = testOrder.Id,
        Product2 = testProd,
        PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id,
        Quantity = 1,
        UnitPrice = 100
    );
    orderItemsToInsert.add(testOrderLine2);**
    insert orderItemsToInsert;

    test.startTest();
    testOrder.Ship_To_Name__c = 'Test update';
    testOrder.ShippingCountry = 'United States';
    update testOrder;

    testOrder.ShippingStreet = '124 Test';
    update testOrder;

    testOrder.ShippingCity = 'Hudson';
    update testOrder;

    testOrder.ShippingState = 'New Jersey';
    update testOrder;

    testOrder.ShippingPostalCode ='12345';
    update testOrder;
    
    testOrderLine.Status__c = 'Error';
    testOrderLine.Error_Message__c = 'Test Error Message';
    update testOrderLine;
    
    testOrder.Status = 'Error';
    update testOrder;

    test.stopTest();

    List<OrderItem> orderLine = [SELECT Ship_To_Name__c FROM OrderItem LIMIT 1];

    system.assertEquals('Test update', orderLine[0].Ship_to_Name__c);

}
}
```

Comment: Can you point exactly which line is throwing the error, its written line `80` but because of commented blocks not able to check which exact line.

Comment: @NagendraSingh  if(p.Lead_Time__c == null){ is line 80

Answer (score 1):

Seems your problem is here:

```
for (orderItem o : itemsMissingStartDate) {
    Integer leadTimeDays = itemsWithLeadTime.get(o.Product2Id).intValue();
    // map may not contain key
}
```

Your `itemsWithLeadTime.get(o.Product2Id)` call can certainly return `null`. You can drop the `.intValue()` call as it serves no purpose here, but then you just move the NPE down one line.

You need to decide what to do when you do not have a lead time for given `Product2Id`. Either you don't touch the `ServiceStartDate__c`, set it to today, or clear it out. The fix will vary depending on which you choose, but if for example you choose the last, you would do:

```
for (orderItem o : itemsMissingStartDate) {
    Decimal leadTime = itemsWithLeadTime.get(o.Product2Id);
    if (leadTime == null) leadTime = 0;
    o.ServiceDate__c = Date.today().addDays(leadTime);
}
```

Comment: I updated the code (see above), but am still getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

Based on the line number you have mentioned.

There might be a null getting entered here `orderedProducts.add(o.Product2);`

So after this line you can write `orderedProducts.remove(null);`, so that it does not contain any null values.

So your code will look like this:

```
for(OrderItem o : trigger.new){
    newOrderItemIds.add(o.Id);
    if(o.ServiceStartDate__c == null){
        updateItemStartDate.add(o);
        orderedProducts.add(o.Product2);
    }
}
orderedProducts.remove(null);
```